# Hibernate fails to auto-create tables in different schemata with @OneToOne relationship

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I want to create a @OneToOne relationship between two tables in different schemata. I'm using Spring, JPA, Hibernate and PostgreSQL. A stripped down version of what I'm trying to do:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="security")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    // ... other stuff ...
}

// -------------------------------------

@Entity
@Table(schema="hr")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="idUser", nullable=false)
    private User user;

    // ... other stuff ...
}
```

This will generate an exception (*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException*) while the hibernate is trying to create everything, caused by:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table hr.employee add constraint FKfx9f6f9b8j7bno8r8unvb21ir foreign key (id_user) references security.user]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:360)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applyForeignKeys(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:481)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: schema "security" does not exist
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2270)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1998)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:570)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:406)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:334)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyStatement.java:410)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:56)
    ... 27 more
```

If I create the tables manually, everything works. If I place both tables in the same schema, everything works.

If I run once without the Employee entity, the **user** table is created, and in a second run, the **employee** table is created successfully.

Any ideas how to solve this? Is there a way to tell hibernate the order which the tables should be created?

Comment: Can you provide your Hibernate-Mapping.xml ?

Comment: @VA31 There is none... I use annotations only for defining the entities

Comment: What is your value of hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto?

Comment: @Alex the hbm2ddl.auto is set to _update_. I have also tried with _create_ with the same result.